# rails 4 nokogiri on Windows 8.1 platform

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm new on Rails and Ruby
I install Ruby with the tool provided by rubyInstaller and it work fine
Then i used gem to downlaod Rails 4
I tried to downlaod it

```
gem install rails
```

and it work
Then my prompt windows ask me to write this:

```
bundle install
```

And it downloaded a lot of new gem
I maked a new app called "App" with rails with this command

```
rails new App
```

And it worked.But when a point the directory of this new app and write this command

```
rails server
```

It give me this error:

```
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri.rb: 29:in `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri (LoadError)
```

there are a lot of other thing but i think that this is the problem.
What i can do?
WIndows 8.1 x64
Ruby 2.2.2 x32

Answer (score 0):

You need to include nokogiri in your Gemfile

Comment: where is?And how i can do this?

Comment: Go to the gemfile file and add `gem 'nokogiri'`

Comment: @Giovanni did this help?

Comment: Sorry i haven't internet connection.I can't find the gem file.I'm a newbie with rails

Comment: C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri.rb:
29:in `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri (LoadError)    
I don't know why,but today ma cmd show me this error.I will edit the post to show to all the error